# How do I use JavaScript fetch in Laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fetch, laravel-8

**Issue:**
So whenever I click the HTML button that activates the Javascript code, I get an error in the console stating:
**POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment 419 (unknown status)**

**What I have tried**

I have tried different ways to get the variable to work, returning it with a view, JSON_ENCODE(), I keep trying to research how to use fetch with Laravel and I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Here is my HTML & Javascript code:

```
<form action="/payment" method="POST">
@csrf
<button class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4" id="checkout-button">Proceed to Checkout</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_*******************');
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');

    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Create a new Checkout Session using the server-side endpoint you
    // created in step 3.
        fetch('/payment', {
            method: 'POST', 
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'url': '/payment',
            },
         })
         .then(function(response) {
             return response.json();
         })
         .then(function(session) {
             return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
         })
         .then(function(result) {
             // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
             // error, you should display the localized error message to your
             // customer using `error.message`.
             if (result.error) {
                 alert(result.error.message);
             }
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
              //console.error('Error:', error);
          });
      });
</script>
</form>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('/payment', [StripePaymentController::class, 'payment']);
```

This is my controller method:

```
    /* Sends the stripe key, and payment info to the stripe api, as long as the payment session */
    public function payment() {
        // Sets up the businesses secret key to receive the payment
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

        // Sets up payment method, and product information
        $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create ([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [[
              'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'product_data' => [
                  'name' => 'T-shirt',
                ],
                'unit_amount' => 2000,
              ],
              'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
            'cancel_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart',
        ]);

        return response()->json(['id' => $session->id]);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's  an error regarding CSRF token mismatch

You will need to manually pass the token in fetch request

```js
fetch('/payment', {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'url': '/payment',
        "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('input[name=_token]').value
    },
})
```

Comment: Oh.... it works... I spent 2 days straight for that... How did you get this information? So I can reference it.

Comment: @RodrigoAlvarez Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-introduction. Remember to accept/upvote the answer if it resolves your issue for the benefit of subsequent visitors

Comment: So for Neanderthals like me who isn't as strong in JavaScript like you, I wanted to ask if 'input[name=token]') grabs the @csrf token created at the form?

Comment: I also noticed you changed the code, what is the con in the previous version?

Comment: Yes indeed. If you look at the hidden input populated by @csrf in devtools you can see the name and value

Comment: Nothing wrong with the previous version. I changed it to vanilla javascript so that it becomes library/framework agnostic. No dependency on library like jquery

Comment: Ohhhhhh What do you recommend for me to get better at my JavaScript, I know only the basics from my University, I graduated a couple months ago.

Comment: Whoaaaa thinking long term. Thanks! I made your answer the accepted one! Sadly I can't upvote due to my low score.

Comment: I would recommend https://beginnerjavascript.com/ course - it's a paid one but worth it. https://javascript30.com/ is another one from the same author and free but it's a bit on intermediate-advance level

Comment: In my case, it is to call store method of a controller with sub-form datas… so I have in fetch `const datas = new FormData(form); const json_datas = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(datas));`  […] and in fetch : `body : json_datas`, thanks